# Consider three square matrices $A, B, C$ of order $n$ (n is odd) satisfying $A^T=A-B$ and $B^T=B-C$, then prove that...

Tags: matrices

> $|C|=2^n|B|$

> $|A+B|=|A-2B|$

> $|B|=0$

Since $$C=B-B^T$$
$$C=A-A^T-(A-A^T)^T$$
$$C=2B$$
$$|C|=2^n|B|$$

How do I prove the other 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A+B = 2A-A^T = (2A^T-A)^T = (A-2(A-A^T))^T = (A-2B)^T$$

gives you number $2$.

$$B = A-A^T = -(A-A^T)^T = -B^T$$

gives you $3$, since the dimension is odd.